# Lagrangian transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, covariance

> I want to prove that the Lagrangian transformation is covariant for $x_{i}\rightarrow q_{i}(x)$ and $x_{i}\rightarrow q_{i}(x,t)$.

So far I've proven that it holds for the first transformation as follows:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{i}}=\frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial q_{a}}\frac{\partial q_{a}}{\partial x_{i}}+\frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial \dot{q}_{a}}\frac{\partial \dot{q}_{a}}{\partial x_{i}}$$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{i}}=\frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial \dot{q}_{a}}\frac{\partial \dot{q}_{a}}{\partial x_{i}}\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{i}}=\frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial \dot{q}_{a}}\frac{\partial q_{a}}{\partial x_{i}}$$

since $\dot{q}_{a}=\frac{\partial q_{a}}{\partial x_{i}}$

If I now try the second transformation ($x_{i}\rightarrow q_{i}(x,t)$) the last relation becomes 
$$\dot{q}_{a}=\frac{\partial q_{a}}{\partial x_{i}}\dot{x_{i}}+\frac{\partial q_{a}}{\partial t}$$,
the second equation still holds but I'm not sure if the first equation holds, considering that $x_{a}=x_{a}(q_{i},t)$. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Such transformations are _point transformations_. You can google that up.